# How can I Download zip file using form submit, and get callback?

Tags: javascript

```
// Step 1
function doSubmit(data1, data2){
    $("#dataForm").remove();

    var form = '';

    form += '<form name="dataForm" id="dataForm" action="" target="hiddenIframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">';
    form += '<input type="text" name="data1" id="data1"/>';
    form += '<input type="text" name="data2" id="data2"/>';
    form += '<div name="dataFormTarget" id="dataFormTarget" style="display:none">';
    form += '</div>';
    form += '</form>';

    $('body').append(form);

    $("#dataForm data1").val(data1);
    $("#dataForm data2").val(data2);

    $("#dataForm").attr("action", "/download/fileDownload.do");
    $("#dataForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : "/download/fileDownload.do",
            async : true,
            type : "POST",
            data : {
                "data1" : data1,
                "data2" : data2
            },
            contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            processData : true,
            success : function(data){
                var blob=new Blob([data]);
                var link=document.createElement('a');
                link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download="testFile.zip";
                link.click();
            }

        });
    });
    $("#dataForm").submit();
}




// Step 2
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/fileDownload.do")
public ModelAndView fileDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelAndView mav) throws Exception {

    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

    Parameter inMap = rDictionary(request, response);

    Parameter outMap = new Parameter();
    Parameter errorMap = new Parameter();

    File file = null;

    try {
        file = new File(inMap.get("data1"));
        errorMap = Util.putErrorMap(ErrConst.ERROR_SUCCESS_CODE, null, inMap);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mav.addObject("outMap", outMap);
    mav = new ModelAndView("downloadView", "downloadFile", file);
    return mav;
}










// Step 3
public class DownloadView extends AbstractView {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DownloadView.class);

    public DownloadView() {
        setContentType("application/download; charset=utf-8");
    }


    @Override
    protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        File file = null;

        try{
            file = (File) model.get("downloadFile");

            response.setContentType(getContentType());

            response.setContentLength((int) file.length());

            String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(file.getName(), "UTF-8");

            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\";");

            response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            FileInputStream fis = null;

            try {

                fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                FileCopyUtils.copy(fis, out);

            } finally {

                if (fis != null) {

                    try {

                        fis.close();

                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    }

                }

            }

            out.flush();
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("file not found Excpetion !!!["+ file.getPath() +"]");
        }

    }
}
```

Hi. 
I'm trying to zip file download, using above code.
after download complete, I must need callback function for next download.

When run this code, download is occured.
but downloaded zip file was crashed..

I don't know what is wrong.

Please give me solution.
Thanks.

(Sorry for short english.)

Comment: Please explain what "downloaded zip was crashed" means. What was actually in the file? Are you sure you got any content? Does it resemble a zip file, or something else?

Comment: downloaded zip file's size is bigger than original zip file (and can't open file)

Comment: Try opening the zip file in a text editor or something other than a zip program so that you can actually inspect its content.